# inserting JSON data into table

Tags: javascript

I have this JSON file:

```
{ maxfare: [ 300, 600, 300, 650, 500, 500, 500, 200, 800 ],
 cabtype: 
 [ 'Crazy Cheesy',
 'Sukanta',
 'Crazy Cheesy',
 'SP\'s Biryani House',
 'Aaoji Khhaoji',
 'Durvankur',
 'House of Paratha',
 'Supreme Corner',
 'The Leaf' ],
 minfare: [ '4.5', '4.0', '4.4', '3.9', '3.9', '3.8', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9' ] }
```

I am trying to insert it into a html table through javascript. For doing the same i am currently doing this:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.className = "medium";
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
                table.appendChild(row);
                var col1 = document.createElement("td");
                col1.innerHTML = this.zomato.cabtype[0];
                row.appendChild(col1);
                var col2 = document.createElement("td");
                col2.innerHTML = this.zomato.maxfare[0];
                row.appendChild(col2);
                var col3 = document.createElement("td");
                col3.innerHTML = this.zomato.minfare[0];
                row.appendChild(col3);
                var row1 = document.createElement("tr");
                table.appendChild(row1);

                var col4 = document.createElement("td");
                col4.innerHTML = this.zomato.cabtype[1];
                row1.appendChild(col4);
                var col5 = document.createElement("td");
                col5.innerHTML = this.zomato.maxfare[1];
                row1.appendChild(col5);
                var col6 = document.createElement("td");
                col6.innerHTML = this.zomato.minfare[1];
                row1.appendChild(col6);
                wrapper.appendChild(table)
```

But as this is long process so I tried to put that in a for loop but unfortunately that doesn't display anything. Can anyone tell whats wrong with it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < zomato.length; i++) {

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = zomato[i][col[j]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: What is zomato?

Comment: its just a name. actually zomato = JSON data. Thats how I am accessing the values of json

Comment: Your title mentions an error, but your question doesn't mention an error anywhere.  Are you getting an error or not?

Comment: I am not getting an error but also not data gets displayed when i try to put it inside loop

Comment: Is it possible that you're merely forgetting to insert the `table` into your document? Edit: actually no, there's no `zomato[0]`

Comment: @ChrisG Do you mean that my loop is right

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha The problem here is that `zomato` isn't an Array.

Comment: yeah is get that now. So what can be done here @ChrisG

Comment: In the future please try to avoid confusion by saying you're getting an error when you aren't actually getting an error.  I've edited your title this time.

Comment: @Amy. Thanks . I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @SLaks can you tell me how is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `keys` of `zomato`. This can be done using `Object.keys(zomato)`, which creates an array containing the keys. Or you simply define one, allowing you to state the order of the columns:

```js
var zomato = {
  maxfare: [300, 600, 300, 650, 500, 500, 500, 200, 800],
  cabtype: ['Crazy Cheesy',
    'Sukanta',
    'Crazy Cheesy',
    'SP\'s Biryani House',
    'Aaoji Khhaoji',
    'Durvankur',
    'House of Paratha',
    'Supreme Corner',
    'The Leaf'
  ],
  minfare: ['4.5', '4.0', '4.4', '3.9', '3.9', '3.8', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9']
};

var table = document.createElement("table");

var keys = ["cabtype", "maxfare", "minfare"];
for (var j = 0; j < zomato[keys[0]].length; j++) {
  var tr = table.insertRow();
  for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML = zomato[keys[k]][j];
  }
}

document.body.insertBefore(table, null);
```